# SQL Results to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to select FirstNames from my SQL DB and then assign them to a JavaScript variable. (Each variable has to be unique)

IE: Having the following database of names:

```
+---------+
|FirstName|
+---------+
|Michael  |
|Kevin    |
|John     |
|Michael  |
|Steven   |
|Michael  |
|Tara     |
|Nancy    |
|Nancy    |
|Steven   |
+---------+
```

And the following query:

```
DECLARE @result varchar(250)
SET @result = ''
SELECT @result = @result + FirstName + ',' FROM Consultants GROUP BY FirstName
select substring(@result, 0, len(@result)) as Name
```

I am able to get all the unique names into a string, something like this:

```
Michael, Kevin, John, Steven, Nancy, Tara
```

This is where I am now stuck... Is there a way to pull the names from the Results and assign them to a variable?

IE:

```
var Consultant 1 = Michael

var Consultant 2 = Kevin

var Consultant 3 = John

// And so forth....
```

I was thinking of building an array out of the names, but I also get stuck trying to do that.

Sorry if this has been asked elsewhere, but I didn't manage to find it anywhere. Also - I hope I have explained this clearly enough.

**EDIT**
I realized I left quite a chunk of info out. This is all happening on my asp page.

So the SQL will be in my `<%asp tags%>` getting the info from the DB, then my JavaScript will follow after that.

Comment: Json is what you're looking for. You can pass the result into a json object (some kind of an array) and use this in your javascript.

Comment: JavaScript can't communicate directly with a database. What server-side language are you using? (PHP, JSP, etc.)

Comment: Why are you appending each name to a string first, if you require that data in an array format? Just `SELECT FirstName FROM Consultants GROUP BY FirstName ORDER BY FirstName ASC;` and pull the full result list via some server side language and format that as a JSON object which could be sent back to the client or written into an output JS file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys. Quite new to the coding scene, but I will readup on the Json you are all mentioning :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is what you should look for.

> I was thinking of building an array out of the names, but I also get
>   stuck trying to do that.

If you have got all your unique names in a string separated by comma, you could build an array like this

```
var string = "Michael,Kevin,John,Steven,Nancy,Tara";
var array =   string.split(",");
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! This helped me build my array and now I just set each name like this:

var string = "<%= ConsultantNames%>";
var array = string.split(",");

var Consultant1Name = array[0];
var Consultant2Name = array[1];
etc.

THANKS SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making your calls using Ajax in combination with jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Then you could encode your result array as JSON and parse it with javascript
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

what I would do ...

```
<?php
$results =  results from your database query
$jsonResults = convert results to JSON. There is a lot of online help for this
?>

<html>
<body>
<head>
<script>
var $json = <?php echo $jsonResults; ?>;

// do stuff with jquery 
</script>
</head>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create array try this

```
var arrNames = result.split(",");
```

if above does not work then try below one

```
var s = '12,34,56';
var firstPos=0;
var secondPos=0;
var arrNames=[];
for ( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++ )
{
    // `s.charAt(i)` gets the character

    if(s.charAt(i) == ',' && i < s.length-1){
        secondPos=i;
        arrNames.push(s.substring(firstPos,secondPos));
        firstPos=i+1;
     }else if(i == s.length-1){
        secondPos=i;
        arrNames.push(s.substring(firstPos,secondPos+1));
     }
}
```